How to extend next-auth User type beta-20
I am using the current beta version
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20"
I have extended the user database entity to include a role.
I have  extended the callback:
callbacks: {
    //usually not needed bug in nextAuth
    async session({ session, user }: any) {
      if (session && user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;
        session.user.role = user.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },

When I use
const session = useSession();   
    const user = session.data?.user;

The variable user does not have the role attribute.
Please let me know how to get role included in the user type?
Many thanks,

Add type folder at the same level with auth.ts file. Then add a new file called next-auth.d.ts inside this folder.
next-auth.d.ts
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        //...
        role: string // <-- add this one
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}

Now you should be able to access the role attribute using the following ways;
Client Component
"use client"

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react" // you should wrap this component with SessionProvider in its parent component

const ClientComponent = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession()
    const role = session?.user?.role || undefined

    return (<></>)
}

Server Component
import { auth } from "auth" // comes from your auth.ts file, NextAuth

const ServerComponent = () => {
    const session = await auth()
    const role = session?.user?.role || undefined

    return (<></>)
}

